# How to pivot a dataframe using multiple column?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

How can I use pandas.pivot_table or any other method to split the following data frame into two?

This is my input data frame:

```
   Method   N    Mean   Max   Min    Median  Mode   Meduim
0   A       5    0.40   0.55  0.25    0.39   N/A    m1
2   A       10   0.26   0.47  0.10    0.25   N/A    m2
1   B       5    0.48   0.62  0.33    0.50   N/A    m1
3   B       7    0.41   0.47  0.36    0.42   0.36   m2
```

And I want to output the two following data frames

```
A      m1       m2
N      5        10  
Mean   0.40     0.26  
Max    0.55     0.47  
Min    0.25     0.10    
Median 0.39    0.25   
Mode   N/A      N/A
```

and

```
B      m1      m2
N      5       7
Mean   0.48    0.41  
Max    0.62    0.47  
Min    0.33    0.36    
Median 0.50    0.42  
Mode   N/A     0.36
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything, can you show us your code ?

Comment: You don't need pivot. Just transpose your data frame (`df.T`) and play with it

Comment: Thank you, I think my fixation with pivot was making it too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Is it pivot?

```
df.set_index(['Method','Meduim']).T
```

gives:

```
Method     A            B      
Meduim    m1     m2    m1    m2
N       5.00  10.00  5.00  7.00
Mean    0.40   0.26  0.48  0.41
Max     0.55   0.47  0.62  0.47
Min     0.25   0.10  0.33  0.36
Median  0.39   0.25  0.50  0.42
Mode     NaN    NaN   NaN  0.36
```

Comment: Thank you, I think my fixation with pivot was making it too complicated.